# Pro AngularJS Chapter 12 | Working With Forms | Using Checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I am working through Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman and have not been able to get the Using Checkboxes example to work.

The example tries to show that you can set attributes ng-true-value="Hurrah!" and ng-false-value="Boo!" and are displayed through ng-model="inputValue".

This is not working.

I am only able to get this sample to work by setting integer values inside ng-true-value and ng-false-value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>Forms</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="todoPanel" class="panel" ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input name="sample" type="checkbox" ng-model="inputValue"
                               ng-true-value="Hurrah!" ng-false-value="Boo!">
                        This is a checkbox
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <p>Model Value: {{inputValue}}</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [input[checkbox]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D#!), `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` accept expressions.  Since you are trying to pass a string literal as the value, you need to enclose them in an addional pair of quotes.

Try `ng-true-value="'Hurrah!'" ng-false-value="'Boo!'"`